# Installing Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) with NSIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nsis, vsix

I'm building my own extension for VS2010 and it has to be deployed outside of Visual Studio Gallery. My NSIS installer does a very good job in installing other parts of software, however I can't figure out how to install .vsix extension.

I tried doing that via VsixInstaller.exe which is a part of Visual Studio, however it does not allow to silently install an extension for any VIsual Studio found on the machine and get a proper error code into the installer.

"VsixInstaller.exe /quiet extension.vsix" returns 0 error code no matter what happens and requires /skuName and /skuVersion which is not trivial to detect automatically.

Can I somehow do that manually? ReSharper for example keeps all the extension binaries in it's "Program Files" folder and somehow makes them available for VIsual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using copy aka:

```
copy xx.vsix "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions"
```

or

```
copy xx.vsix %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft"
```

Answer (score 0):

Registering Visual Studio extensions is complicated process. For **pre** 2010 VS editions you need to copy appropriate files (.dll/.zip template/.regpkg...) into some folder and then write keys into registry with paths, settings, etc. (many, many keys).

These keys/settings are based on extension you are developing (LanguageService, Package, Add-in, ...)

**After** 2010 VS editions have new feature - .vsix extensions which is simple .zip archive containing all required files and registry keys.

You need to copy this .vsix file into some folder (recommended is inside VS install directory or other known folder as %VSInstallDir%\\) and then setup VS to load it (like running devenv.com /setup)

Read this blog for more info about discovering VS extensions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/19/how-vsix-extensions-are-discovered-and-loaded-in-vs-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit closer now. So I can install extension just unpacking vsix into any subfolder under IDE/Extensions. I haven't managed to somehow tell VS to load the extension from my own folder under Program Files though. However, when I delete the folder, extension becomes grayed out in the Extension Manager even after I restart Visual Studio.